# Android sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/package name/*.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I develop the application for using in my company. I got this error when I tried to install my updated-application. The error was happened at this line of code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteOpenHelperDAO.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();
```

I put the try/catch in there and the error messages show that "unable to open database file"

and the logCat shown me that:

```
04-02 11:50:38.626: I/Database(16526): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
04-02 11:50:38.626: E/Database(16526):  sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/myappPackage/databases/mydb.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
04-02 11:50:38.642: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(16526): Couldn't open mydb.db for writing (will try read-only):
```

then I got a ***Force close***.

This is my **getInstance** method

```
public static synchronized SQLiteOpenHelperDAO getInstance(Context context) {

    if (helper == null) {
        helper = new SQLiteOpenHelperDAO(context);
    }

    if (dbRefCounter > 1000)
        dbRefCounter = 0;
    else
        dbRefCounter++;

    Log.i(TAG, "Return new reference to mPos database. Current number of references=" + String.valueOf(dbRefCounter));

    return helper;
}
```

I have about 3 devices for testing and
this error always happen only on the **Samsung devices** when I try to upgrade the application but It works fine with my Sony XSL and Chinese Android tablet.

I don't have any idea how to fix this problem. 
Please help
Regards.

Comment: Can you write getInstance method of SQLiteOpenHelperDAO

Comment: post your full code Database Helper

Comment: please add `getInstance()` java code.

Comment: I just add my getInstance method, Please check.

Comment: My application works perfectly if I do clean-install(uninstall the old version and install a new version) to Samsung device.But I won't work if I replace a current application with the new application. But another devices works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

If it works then check your getInstance() in Database class.

```
 SQLiteOpenHelperDAO dbAdapter = new  SQLiteOpenHelperDAO(this);

 SQLiteDatabase db = dbAdapter .getReadableDatabase();
```

or here is getInstance().

```
public static synchronized SQLiteOpenHelperDAO  getInstance(Context ctx)
    {
        if (dbAdapter == null) 
            dbAdapter = new SQLiteOpenHelperDAO(ctx);
        }

        return dbAdapter;
    }
```